# Android app google maps showing grey tiles and not map!

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I followed this guide here perfectly and have gone through it again but when I run the program on my google avd the page loads but only grey tiles appear and it doesn't show a map which it should.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have the `Internet` permission?

Comment: yeah i have both everything correctly as it should be. the apiKey, the INTERNET permission, and the googlemaps library in the manifest. I've followed the guide countless times and I still get the same problem. the grey tiles....
I dont think anyone has an answer for it?

Comment: 04-16 19:26:07.693: ERROR/ActivityThread(204): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-16 19:26:07.723: ERROR/ActivityThread(204): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-16 19:26:07.803: ERROR/ActivityThread(204): Failed to find provider info for com.google.settings
04-16 19:26:07.933: DEBUG/ddm-heap(210): Got feature list request
04-16 19:26:08.723: INFO/MapActivity(204): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
04-16 19:26:08.733: ERROR/MapActivity(204): Couldn't get connection factory client

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was facing the same issue a couple of days ago and figured out that something related to APK signing was acting weird. The solution was to set the “Custom debug keystore” setting (empty by default) to the same value as the “Default debug keystore” in the Eclipse preferences.

Comment: that did not work for me... can't get the maps to show and have tried it all... i use svn with a teammate and it works in her computer just fine :(

Comment: @tg I've tried your suggestion, didn't do it for me. Yet following on @mga's advice, I actually asked my team mate to send me his debug.keystore, and since he had generated an API Key (under Linux I think), the tiles showed up. I think I didn't generate the right MD5s, all the keys I have generated under Windows started with a baffling "0TAB" sequence, and this wasn't the case for my team mate's generated API Key. Thank you !

Comment: I had the same issue, and one of my collegues is having the problem too. I solved it by generating a new debug keystore and registered for a new API key. I couldn't figure out how that solved the problem, I concluded that I must have messed up something during the first registration.

Comment: M facing same issue.. I regenerated new key but still no Map content displayed

Comment: How to do the same for Android studio?

Answer (score 10):

You either have the wrong value for `android:apiKey` in your `MapView`, or you do not have the `INTERNET` permission, or you do not have Internet access.

Answer (score 7):

Worth remembering when you are ready to release to marketplace to generate new RSA fingerprint and API key from your actual keystore as opposed to the default debug keystore.

Also if you are developing on different machines you'll have different keystores and hence different RSA fingerprints. That had me stumped for a while when google maps suddenly stopped working when developing at home.

Comment: I only have a single debug.keystore, and copy it over to every machine I work on, if you register to maps, facebook, admob and others, it is the only way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem : grey tiles and not map.

My solution was to move :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside `<application>< /application>`

It works now! I hope it can help anybody!

Comment: Great man! it worked great for me. Is this stated somewhere or how did you find this out?

Comment: More like pretty obvious :) You do need Internet access to download map data.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem in another way:
I'm working on hackintosh mac os. So I gone to terminal and type:

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore /Users/hackintosh/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

It generated me a certificate's MD5 fingerprint like:
"94:1E:43:49:87:73:BB:E6:A6:88:D7:20:F1:8E:B5:98"..
After it, I went to google maps api site

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup?hl=en-US

and paste the certificate's MD5 fingerprint. The google maps api returns me an API Key that I glued in the API Key field on my XML's app.
And there's no more grey fields =)

Answer (score 0):

If you're are using the debug keystore to sign your app you need to generate a key for it too, in addition to the cert you plan to use for production.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know weather this will work for you or not.

Try following methods:

1) Check your API key when you are connected to svn as you might be sharing other person's key. If you do not have one then create it from this link: [google map md5 generation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)

and then generate api key from [api key](https://developers.google.com/maps/signup)

2) check manifest for INTERNET permissions

> android.permission.INTERNET

3)sometimes problem arises due to  AVD. Go to Avd manager and increase Max VM application heap size and device RAM size.