# Map is not Showing in Android device

Tags: android, google-maps

In my app, i used google map feature.For that i used my own keystore and created MD5 fingerprint.Later i got my xml based on that MD5 from google.

Problem:

It is working in  emulator.But not showing anything in real device.But Grid is visible.

Sample--class

```
public class First extends MapActivity {
private MapController mc;
private MapView mapView;

private static double current_lat;
private static double current_long;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mc = mapView.getController();
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)   getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mNetworkListener);

GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int)current_lat*(1000000), (int)current_long*(1000000));            
mc.animateTo(p);  

}
private static LocationListener mNetworkListener = new LocationListener() 
{
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
}

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
         public void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
             current_lat = location.getLatitude();
             current_long = location.getLongitude();
             System.out.println("*** i'm here"+current_lat);

    }

};
@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name" >

   <activity
     android:name=".First"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
</application>
```

Main

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
 android:id="@+id/mapview"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:apiKey="0wINx0c2YuEd3mkyPwidZyeoz_HiyN3jrts-Q" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat

```
 08-10 14:27:56.841: W/MapActivity(20815): Recycling dispatcher       android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@405b  9458
 08-10 14:27:56.851: V/MapActivity(20815): Recycling map object.
 08-10 14:27:56.901: I/MapActivity(20815): Handling network change   notification:CONNECTED
 08-10 14:27:56.901: E/MapActivity(20815): Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Can anybody figure out why map not showing in device.Thanks in advance

Comment: Regenerate the API key and try again

Comment: i had done that many times..But only grid is shown in device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2641197/735675 try this. Same exact problem.

Comment: By using Custom Debug Keystore ,it is showing "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" error in eclipse preference...How to correct this?

Comment: Actually logcat showing some warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem which i figured out is the Mapview will show only if the app is downloaded from android market,since we are using signed api key.

I think thats why ,it is not showing while running through eclipse.

Comment: No, of course MapView can be displayed through android emulator. For this you must obtain a google maps api key from: https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

Comment: for emulator,it will show using default keystore.But for device,we should create keystore manually ,i think so.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your mapview xml code with this and try again.

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="Your API Key"
/>
```

Also make sure your device has Internet access.