# android.view.inflateException while trying to load a map in an android app

Tags: android, android-layout

I know this question has already been asked but none of the solutions helped me. I am new  to android development and I am trying to load a map in my app. But i get the following exception:

```
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:149)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1300)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:260)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5020)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    ... 11 more
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513): <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at maps.af.cf.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at maps.af.ay.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at maps.af.al.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at maps.af.be.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at maps.af.bd.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at cmj.onTransact(SourceFile:107)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:326)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapFragmentDelegate$a$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$4.b(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:900)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1184)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:291)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
12-12 12:37:26.542: E/AndroidRuntime(19513):    ... 21 more
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDTSCB95Kz4Jndj5AxBUGPE_I0g9DwNjsI" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="x.y.z.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="x.y.z.BookCabActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Following is the fragment block in the xml:

```
 <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pickLoc" />
```

and the Activity.java is as follows:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


public class BookCabActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.book_cab);
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map= fm.getMap(); 

    }


}
```

Please help me with this. I am stuck to this and cannot move forward. And sorry for my poor english. :)

Comment: You published your com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY. This should be value known only by developer. That's why you should generate new key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
```

Add the below in manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

Check the docs under Specifying permissions

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#getting_the_google_maps_android_api_v2

Edit:

[image]

Comment: Thanx Raghu. It worked. The map has loaded but I still cannot see anything inside the map. By that I mean, roads and routes are still not there . All I can see is a greyish screen with google written on the bottom left corner. Can you please tell me the problem?

Comment: @user3094229 is your api key right? Have you enabled maps for android in google play console?

Comment: @user3094229 also testing on device right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641197/android-app-google-maps-showing-grey-tiles-and-not-map

Comment: I checked my api key and it is fine. Can you please tell me how to enable maps for android in google play console? pardon my ignorance.

Comment: @user3094229 follow the link in my post. the docs has all the details you need to get your code working

Comment: Hi Raghu,I tried all the suggestions in that question. But nothing seems to be working for me. Can you help?

Comment: gnerate a new key and try. if its a coding error i can help. i can only suggest. But have you referenced the google play services library project? any exceptions errors?

Comment: Yes, I have referenced to the google play services project.Also, I have created new key. And I dont see any errors/exceptions in the logcat.

Comment: Is this any service that I have to activate while generating the api key, like the way i activated Google Maps Android API v2. I dont know how to enable maps for android in the google play console. Again Pardon me for my ignorance.

Comment: @user3094229 that is also there in the docs. pls follow the steps under obtaining api key in the link posted in my post. follow all the steps and it will work. Other than that i can't suggest anything more

Comment: @user3094229 check the snap shot of how it looks

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```